# Correct Way to Design a Responsive Column Focused Div Table

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

I want to add a wide table to my website, consisting of many columns, but few headings; all the subsequent cells are tightly linked to the heading they fall under. The table does not fit on the width of cellphone browsers. I'd like the table to split at the headings.

I attempted the following, the container div is used to simulate a page width change:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 150px;
}
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!-- The container is horizontally resizable, to simulate a page width change. -->
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flex-container'>
    <div class='table'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Heading 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='table'>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='cell'>One</div>
            <div class='cell'>Two</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='table'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Heading 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Three</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this the correct way to achieve this? Are there better methods or conventions that I can adhere to?

Comment: Not sure about "better" but twitter bootstrap wraps the table in a `div` that scrolls horizontally at mobile width and leaves the table as is. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: Your solution works, but the tables are not using their space optimally since their width is fixed. For the effect you have right now you could have also used `display:inline-block` which is easier and more compatible with older browsers. No idea how to make it better, though. Sry.

Comment: I was considering wrapping the table in a scroll-able environment, but I thought the stacking columns might be easier to read. I'm not sure if that was the right decision now.